# Unity3D Automatic Mipmap

Tags: unity

I'm using Unity3D. I'm working advanced topics. For example Mipmap.

How I can automatic mipmap (use camera distance) for textures?

Thank you.

Comment: In my experience, Unity automatically enables mipmapping on imported textures by default, unless you go into the advanced settings and manually disable it. Are you finding a case where the mipmaps don't seem to be working using default settings?

Answer (score 1):

Just check the box in texture import settings to enable mipmap generation. They are automatically in use.

[image]

For the mipmaps to have any effect, you need to have bilinear or trilinear filtering enabled. Nothing else has to be done if you are not manually trying to read the mip levels in custom shaders.